# Error to create meanjs project with yo Generator

Tags: node.js, meanjs, node-modules, mean.io, yo

I am beginner to means js ,I did the setup for meanjs from [here](http://meanjs.org/generator.html).

I have use the following commands to create meanjs project with some question answering.

```
        santosh@santosh:~/Documents/Projects$ yo meanjs
        Native thread-sleep not available.
        This will result in much slower performance, but it will still work.
        You should re-install spawn-sync or upgrade to the lastest version of node if possible.
        Check /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/external-editor/node_modules/spawn-sync/error.log for more details
        Native thread-sleep not available.
        This will result in much slower performance, but it will still work.
        You should re-install spawn-sync or upgrade to the lastest version of node if possible.
        Check /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/tabtab/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/external-editor/node_modules/spawn-sync/error.log for more details
        You're using the official MEAN.JS generator.
        ? What mean.js version would you like to generate? 0.4.0
        0.4.0
        ? In which folder would you like the project to be generated? This can be chang
        ed later. mytest
        Cloning the MEAN repo.......
        ? What would you like to call your application? MEAN
        ? How would you describe your application? Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, 
        Express, AngularJS, and Node.js
        ? How would you describe your application in comma seperated key words? MongoDB
        , Express, AngularJS, Node.js
        ? What is your company/author name? santosh
        ? Would you like to generate the article example CRUD module? Yes
        ? Would you like to generate the chat example module? Yes
        Running npm install for you....
        This may take a couple minutes.
        Error: stderr maxBuffer exceeded.
            at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:686:13)
            at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
            at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
            at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
            at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
            at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
            at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
            at Pipe.onread (net.js:526:21)
        santosh@santosh:~/Documents/Projects$
```

Please tell me why ***Error: stderr maxBuffer exceeded.*** are there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely related with old Node.js and NPM packages. Update those and the problem should disappear.

A similar problem was solved [here](https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs/issues/138).

Comment: Thanks your answer is helpful for me.